# How is the ipcRenderer argument JSON object losing data when passed from an Angular 7 service?

Tags: json, angular, electron, ipcrenderer

I am having a strange issue with an Angular 7.1.1 and Electron 4.1.4 project.

**Data Flow:**

1. Angular Component "Report Builder" collects report configuration options from a FormGroup and FormControl validated form and sends data to docx-templater.service

   - User Button triggers createReport() function
   - When submitting options for a complete report, the createReport() function calls dataService's fnGetCompleteControlList() which returns properly configured JSON asynchronously.
   - with a .then() function after the async data retrieval, the createReport() function combines the output directory which is part of the configuration form and sends both to the docx-templater.service's createCompleteDocument() function. Once the promise is returned it updates the UI.
2. Angular Service "docx-templater"'s createCompleteDocument function passes the data and folder values to the ipcRenderer.send for the electron "writeCompleteDocument" channel and returns a promise.
3. In my main.ts, I have an ipcMain.on for the "writeCompleteDocument" channel that passes the data to a write-docx function for processing that data into a word document.

**Problem:**
When the data gets to my write-docx function it is missing a sub array of objects that are essential to the export process.

I have verified that the data is perfect in the Chrome Developer Tools console of electron at the moment just before it sends the data to the docx-templater.service and just before that service sends it to the ipcRenderer (meaning my data service and Report Builder functions are working as designed). When I check the data in the main.ts by saving the data off to a JSON file it is missing the controls sub array within the second object of the JSON only. The controls sub array shows up in the first object as expected.

I will note that what is coming out of the ipcMain function is a properly formed JSON file so it has really just excluded the "controls" sub array and is not truncating due to memory or buffer limits or anything like that.

```
report-builder.component.ts

createReport() {
    if (this.reportBuilderFG.get('allControls').value) {
      this.db.fnGetCompleteControlList()
        .then((groups: Group[]) => {
          this.word.createCompleteDocument(groups, this.reportBuilderFG.get('folder').value + '\\filename.docx')
          .then(() => {
            this.openSnackBar(this.reportBuilderFG.get('folder').value + '\\filename.docx created successfully');
          });
        });
    } else {
      // Do other stuff
    }
```

```
docx-templater.service.ts

createCompleteDocument(data, folder: string): Promise<boolean> {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      console.log(data) <=== Data is perfect here.
      ipcRenderer.send('writeCompleteDocument', {data: data, folder: folder});
      resolve();
    });
  }
```

```
main.ts
import { writeCompleteDocument } from './node_scripts/write-docx';

ipcMain.on('writeCompleteDocument', (event, arg) => {
  fs.writeFileSync("IPCdata.json", arg.data); // <==== Part of the data is missing here.
  writeCompleteDocument(arg.data, arg.folder);
});
```

```
Good Data Example (some keys and objects excluded for brevity)
[
  {
    "name": "General Security",
    "order": 1,
    "subgroups": [
      {
        "_id": "GOV",
        "name": "Governance",
        "order": 1,
        "controls": [
          {
            "group": "GS",
            "subgroup": "GOV",
            "active": true,
            "printOrder": 1,
            "name": "This is my GS control name",
            "requirements": [
              {
                "id": "SA01",
                "active": true,
                "order": 1,
                "type": "SA",
                "applicability": [
                  "ABC",
                  "DEF",
                  "GHI"
                ],
              },
              { ... 3 more  }
            ],
            "_id": "GSRA-03",
            "_rev": "1-0cbdefc93e56683bc98bae3a122f9783"
          },
          { ... 3 more }
    ],
    "_id": "GS",
    "_rev": "1-b94d1651589eefd5ef0a52360dac6f9d"
  },
  {
    "order": 2,
    "name": "IT Security",
    "subgroups": [
      {
        "_id": "PLCY",
        "order": 1,
        "name": "Policies",
        "controls": [ <==== This entire sub array is missing when exporting from IPC Main
          {
            "group": "IT",
            "subgroup": "PLCY",
            "active": true,
            "printOrder": 1,
            "name": "This is my IT control name",
            "requirements": [
              {
                "id": "SA01",
                "active": true,
                "order": 1,
                "type": "SA",
                "applicability": [
                  "ABC",
                  "DEF",
                  "GHI"
                ],
              }
            ],
            "_id": "GSRA-03",
            "_rev": "1-0cbdefc93e56683bc98bae3a122f9783"
          }
      }
    ],
    "_id": "IT",
    "_rev": "2-e6ff53456e85b45d9bafd791652a945c"
  }
]
```

I would have expected the ipcRenderer to pass a JSON exactly as it is to the ipcMain.on function, but somehow it is trimming part of the data. I have even tried strigifying the data before sending it to the renderer and then parsing it on the other side but that did nothing.

Could this be an async thing? I am at a loss of where to go next to debug and find what idiot mistake I made in the process.

Also, I realize that the above data flow seems overly complex for what I am doing, and that I can probably do it easier, but it makes sense (kinda) for the way the whole application is structured so I am going to go with it if I can squash this bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your `createCompleteDocument()` function is set up incorrectly. A quick search showed me that [`ipcRenderer`](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-renderer#ipcrenderer) is an async function, but you are responding to it (almost) synchronously.

You have the following, which is (probably) incorrect (actually it's definitely incorrect, because you've typed typed the return as `Promise<boolean>` when it is `Promise<void>`):

```
createCompleteDocument(data, folder: string): Promise<boolean> {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    ipcRenderer.send('writeCompleteDocument', {data: data, folder: folder});
    resolve();
  });
}
```

[`ipcRenderer#send()`](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-renderer#ipcrenderersendchannel-arg1-arg2-) is async but you are calling `resolve()` immediately afterwards without waiting for the function to resolve. This probably explains why adding the `setTimeout()` is fixing the problem for you. Looking at the [`ipcRenderer` docs](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-renderer#ipcrenderer), the following probably does what you want:

```
createCompleteDocument(data, folder: string): Promise<Event> {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    ipcRenderer.once('writeCompleteDocument', resolve);
    ipcRenderer.send('writeCompleteDocument', {data: data, folder: folder});
  });
}
```

Looks like the callback is passed an [Event object](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-renderer#event-object).

Another option would be to simply replace `ipcRenderer#send()` with [`ipcRenderer#sendSync()`](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-renderer#ipcrenderersendsyncchannel-arg1-arg2-) in your original code, but as pointed out in that method's documentation :

> Sending a synchronous message will block the whole renderer process, unless you know what you are doing you should never use it.

Making use of `ipcRenderer#send()` and `ipcRenderer#once()` is almost definitely the way to go.

Seperately, you can clean up the code by switching to [async/await functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function). For example:

```
async createReport(): Promise<void> {
  if (this.reportBuilderFG.get('allControls').value) {
    const groups: Group[] = await this.db.fnGetCompleteControlList();

    await this.word.createCompleteDocument(
      groups,
      this.reportBuilderFG.get('folder').value + '\\filename.docx'
    );

    // Unclear if this function is actually async 
    await this.openSnackBar(
      this.reportBuilderFG.get('folder').value +
        '\\filename.docx created successfully'
    );
  } else {
    // Do other stuff
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by adding a 1000 ms timeout after my fnGetCompleteControlList() data pull in the report-builder.component.ts. It seems like I have a lot more work todo with learning async functions. :-(

```
report-builder.component.ts

createReport() {
    if (this.reportBuilderFG.get('allControls').value) {
      this.db.fnGetCompleteControlList()
        .then((groups: Group[]) => {
          setTimeout(() => {
              this.word.createCompleteDocument(groups, this.reportBuilderFG.get('folder').value + '\\filename.docx')
              .then(() => {
                  this.openSnackBar(this.reportBuilderFG.get('folder').value + '\\filename.docx created successfully');
              });
          }, 1000);
        });
    } else {
      // Do other stuff
    }
```